# AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER failure

Tags: mysql, triggers

First, **create the trigger**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateSentiero_AfterUpdatingTappa
AFTER UPDATE ON TAPPA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

//NEW.tempo and OLD.tempo would refers to TAPPA "tempo" and "lunghezza", really? I ask you this because SENTIERO has it own "tempo" and "lunghezza"
IF (NEW.tempo is not null) and NOT (NEW.tempo=OLD.tempo) THEN

        UPDATE SENTIERO 
        SET tempo=0;

END IF;
END$$
```

Then, **run the query**:

```
UPDATE SENTIERO
SET tempo=null;
```

It seems the TRIGGER doesn't work and i don't know the reason.

**NEW.tempo and OLD.tempo could be NULL** (i suppose they refers to TAPPA, because it's a TRIGGER ON TAPPA) that's the reason for i've written that IF condition.

---

**EDIT ::**

One INSTANCE of SENTIERO has multiple INSTANCES of TAPPA, so one INSTANCE of SENTIERO collect the values of it own "tempo" and "lunghezza" TAPPA INSTANCES

```
IF (NEW.tempo is not null) and NOT (NEW.tempo=OLD.tempo) THEN

    IF (OLD.tempo is NOT NULL) THEN

            UPDATE SENTIERO
            SET tempo=tempo - OLD.tempo + NEW.tempo
            WHERE (tempo is NOT NULL) and IDsentiero IN ( SELECT DISTINCT IDsentiero
                                                         FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA AS sht
                                                         WHERE NEW.IDtappa=sht.IDtappa);
    ELSE

            UPDATE SENTIERO
            SET tempo=tempo + NEW.tempo
            WHERE (tempo is NOT NULL) and IDsentiero IN ( SELECT DISTINCT IDsentiero
                                                          FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA AS sht
                                                          WHERE NEW.IDtappa=sht.IDtappa);

            UPDATE SENTIERO
            SET tempo=NEW.tempo
            WHERE (tempo is NULL) and IDsentiero IN ( SELECT DISTINCT IDsentiero
                                                      FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA AS sht
                                                      WHERE NEW.IDtappa=sht.IDtappa); 
    END IF;


END IF;
```

But when I try to run

```
UPDATE TAPPA
SET tempo=9
WHERE IDtappa=0;
//where instance of IDtappa=0 has "tempo"'s value=NULL
```

it doesn't work

---

**TABLES DATA:**

```
SENTIERO              |    SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA       |  TAPPA
IDsentiero  time      |    IDsentiero  IDtappa     |  IDtappa  time    
   0         7.5      |        0          0        |     0      null      
                      |        0          1        |     1      1.45     
                      |        0          2        |     2      2.3   
                      |        0          5        |     5      1.45
                      |        0          8        |     8      2.3
```

**The first time** (update on tappa, set tempo=2 where IDtappa=0) **the trigger doesn't work**.

**NOTE: OLD.tempo is NULL, SENTIERO.tempo is not null**

**But the second time** (update on tappa, set tempo=3 where IDtappa=0) **the trigger works**.

**The derived data** calculated on SENTIERO's "tempo", for IDsentiero=0, **HAS CHANGED: 8.5**

**It seems that it has done: 7.5 - 2 +3**, so it seems it has been taken the right condition.

**NOTE: OLD.tappa is NOT NULL, SENTIERO.tempo is NOT NULL**

So the problem is with the NULL value of TAPPA.tempo

Comment: What are the existing tempo values of SENTIERO rows associated with your sample query? You've checked to make sure that there are associating records in SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA, right? The updated trigger is applied to what table?

Comment: Check the data; i've also explained the trigger 's behavior and
given you a cleaner trigger

Comment: Thanks for that. `So the problem is with the NULL value of TAPPA.tempo` indeed, my updated answer should address this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't fire the trigger. Here's why:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateSentiero_AfterUpdatingTappa
AFTER UPDATE ON TAPPA
```

The trigger only fires after updates are made to table TAPPA.

```
UPDATE SENTIERO
SET tempo=null;
```

Your test query is updating table SENTIERO, and setting tempo to null, which is filtered out by the trigger's IF conditional. Try updating TAPPA instead, like this:

```
UPDATE TAPPA
SET tempo=5;
```

This query should cause SENTIERO's tempo values to get set to zero, assuming there's a tempo value != 5 in that table.

Note that it appears your trigger will affect **every row** in SENTIERO. Perhaps you should include some kind of ID matching between the two tables? For example:

```
UPDATE SENTIERO 
SET tempo=0
WHERE SENTIERO.ID = NEW.ID;
```

---

In response to new question:

Your IF statement:

```
IF (NEW.tempo is not null) and NOT (NEW.tempo=OLD.tempo) THEN
```

Your test query:

```
UPDATE TAPPA
SET tempo=9
WHERE IDtappa=0;
//where instance of IDtappa=0 has "tempo"'s value=NULL
```

Given the comment, it's clear the IF block isn't being entered. You're comparing a non-null value against null. This yields null. You need to use [the null safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), `<=>`. Your IF statement should look like this instead:

```
IF (NEW.tempo is not null) and NOT (NEW.tempo<=>OLD.tempo) THEN
```

Comment: ok excuse me ..wrong example ^^. it works, but the real problem was another. I'll edit the question just in 2 minutes. I hope you'll help me, thanks anyway.

Comment: Ooohhh yesss! Long life to you :)